# I am unable to create dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am unable to create a dictionary whose structure is like :

```
"aggs": {
        "4": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "1m",
                "time_zone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
            },
            "aggs": {
                "5": {
                    "range": {
                        "field": "system.core.idle.pct",
                        "ranges": [{"from": 0, "to": 0.001}, {"from": 0.001, "to": 1}],
                        "keyed": true,
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "2": {"max": {"field": "system.core.system.pct"}},
                        "3": {"max": {"field": "system.core.idle.pct"}},
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

Mostly I am getting the issue in creating aggs:5 inside aggs:4 and then looping it. I need to do it for multiple aggs. the number of agg id can be upto 1000 also.

I am trying to derive it from the dictionary:

```
"aggs": [
        {"id": "1", "enabled": true, "type": "count", "schema": "metric", "params": {}},
        {
            "id": "2",
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "max",
            "schema": "metric",
            "params": {"field": "system.core.system.pct", "customLabel": "system"},
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "max",
            "schema": "metric",
            "params": {"field": "system.core.idle.pct", "customLabel": "idle"},
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "date_histogram",
            "schema": "bucket",
            "params": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "m",
                "customInterval": "2h",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "extended_bounds": {},
            },
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "range",
            "schema": "bucket",
            "params": {
                "field": "system.core.idle.pct",
                "ranges": [{"from": 0, "to": 0.001}, {"from": 0.001, "to": 1}],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Can anyone show the code how to execute it. Basically I am failing in creating nested dictionary.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You haven't actually told us what wrong output or error code you're seeing.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am unable to create a dictionary like above using the below info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using JSON data.
You can see this link https://realpython.com/python-json/.
You can use the inbuilt JSON lib to covert the whole thing in a dict
Basically something like this

```
json_string = """
{
    "researcher": {
        "name": "Ford Prefect",
        "species": "Betelgeusian",
        "relatives": [
            {
                "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
                "species": "Betelgeusian"
            }
        ]
    }
}
"""
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: I need to create a abouve dict using the below json file.

Comment: You can see the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

add whole structure in `{}`, and replace `true` to `True`.

```
{"aggs": {
        "4": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "1m",
                "time_zone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
            },
            "aggs": {
                "5": {
                    "range": {
                        "field": "system.core.idle.pct",
                        "ranges": [{"from": 0, "to": 0.001}, {"from": 0.001, "to": 1}],
                        "keyed": True,
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "2": {"max": {"field": "system.core.system.pct"}},
                        "3": {"max": {"field": "system.core.idle.pct"}},
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    }}
```

```
{'aggs': {'4': {'date_histogram': {'field': '@timestamp',
    'interval': '1m',
    'time_zone': 'Asia/Kolkata',
    'min_doc_count': 1},
   'aggs': {'5': {'range': {'field': 'system.core.idle.pct',
      'ranges': [{'from': 0, 'to': 0.001}, {'from': 0.001, 'to': 1}],
      'keyed': True},
     'aggs': {'2': {'max': {'field': 'system.core.system.pct'}},
      '3': {'max': {'field': 'system.core.idle.pct'}}}}}}}}
```